# Why always getting last row from json array result when iterate through with Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, ajax

I have json data in this structure

here is my json code 
https://jsonblob.com/309e8861-7f26-11e7-9e0d-cf3972f3635e

and here is my jquery code example

```
$("#getJsonData").click(function(){
    $.get(base_url + 'roles/index', function(data) {
        var data = $.parseJSON(data);
        $.each(data, function(index, val) {
            $("#result").html("<p>" + val.name + "</p>");
        });
    });
});
```

HTML file

```
<button id="getJsonData">Load role list</button>

    <div id="result"></div>
```

I don't get this, I get every value from json in console when do console.log, but when use html method to display result as html in screen it just showing last value from ending last json array. What is wrong here?

Answer (score 2):

jquery .html always overrite previous html so we cant use html in loop section instead of that we can use append it simply append your p tag in result div
Instead of using this:-

```
$("#result").html("<p>" + val.name + "</p>");
```

use like this:-

```
$("#result").append("<p>" + val.name + "</p>");
```

Comment: But it will append same data result over and over clicking the button, is it right way even?

Comment: can you post your present output in screenshot?

Answer (score 0):

You are overwriting the html with the code

```
$("#result").html("<p>" + val.name + "</p>");
```

Instead you can store the result in variable and then you write it to the element.Like this

```
$("#getJsonData").click(function(){
  $.get(base_url + 'roles/index', function(data) {
    var data = $.parseJSON(data);
    var html = '';
    $.each(data, function(index, val) {
        html +="<p>" + val.name + "</p>";
    });        
    $("#result").html(html);
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code should be :

```
$("#getJsonData").click(function(){
$.get(base_url + 'roles/index', function(data) {
    var data = $.parseJSON(data);
    var listHtml="";
    $.each(data, function(index, val) {
       listHtml=listHtml+ "<p>" + val.name + "</p>";
    });
   $("#result").html(listHtml);
});
```

});

And Html should be same as your

```
<button id="getJsonData">Load role list</button>

<div id="result"></div>
```

Working example is [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/7cGFArerHK8wPm2REbg2?p=preview)